# Binary Search on huge SQL Data with PHP

Tags: php, sql, arrays, binary-search

Is it possible to perform a binary search in PHP on huge data which is stored in an array from an sql database?

Let´s say the datasets got one or more indices. And I would like to find a special data column, from which the index is known. But the PHP array index is not the same as the dataset index. So, the php array is unsorted. Can I still perform binary search on this data record?

I found [this](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Search/Binary_search#PHP) algorithm for PHP binary search. But this only works if the array index represents also the data index from the searched dataset.

Comment: Either use the database to sort the data or, better yet, build an index on the key column(s) and let the database do the work it is designed to do.

Comment: If you can read the database, you can make the database find the value you are looking for; simply: `select ... from ... where [your search condition goes here]`

Comment: sometimes it´s better to get a huge set of data from the database and query the needed data in the huge array locally, because this method is sometimes faster, than let it do the database (long roundtrip times can be avoid by doing this). This follows a design pattern as used in ABAP, too: Cache huge data locally and query it many times. This is much faster than getting it always fresh from the database. That´s what I meant in my question.

Comment: Then you need a local database too, You can use mem-cache for caching and use sql to search data.

Comment: nice and simple solution. But I wanna do it the hard way^^
With object serialization to disk and unserialize it, when needed.